# Deploy on Worklight very slow

Tags: android, iphone, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm working on application, and it takes it about 5~7 minutes to deploy edited javascripts and htmls.

Is that right, wasting so much time to deploy a single app?

Is there a way to deploy on 'light deploy' mode, or deploy only static files (js, html, css)?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear.
You do not mention where you are attempting to deploy (command line, studio, production server), nor how you are attempting to deploy it (the steps you have taken). You also do not mention the structure of your application - whether it is a bare-bones one, or is it based on some additional framework like Dojo or jQuery Mobile or anything else, its size and contents and so on. Without this, who knows?

Otherwise, there is no option to "light deploy". The deployer deploys any and all application web resources.

Comment: we have one app, deploy through worklight cli `wl deploy`. Is there a lot of adapters and I cannot say what framework we are using. The question objective is to know a way to optimize the deploy. Again, I have no experience with worklight, so, be patient.

Comment: There is no way to optimize deployment other than checking if your app is not excessively and unneedingly large which will affect the filesize, which will affect the upload duration.

Comment: @IdanAdar, is there a LiveReload feature on Ibm Worklight?

Comment: Depends on your version of Worklight.

Comment: What about the IBM Worklight 6.2 ? I'm facing the same problem that @hebergentilin and all that I need to do is editing some html and it takes a lot of time because a need to redeploy all te application

Comment: fast reloading is available starting MobileFirst 6.3